# How to get payments beyond pending in PesaPal demo system

Tags: payment-gateway

I'm building a site using PesaPal for payments.

Using PesaPal demo system (which is for testing) I have payments requests being made and I can see them in the PesaPal dashboard, but they never progress beyond pending.

How do I get PesaPal demo system to process payments?

Comment: same issue here. can't find any solution.

Comment: I've spoken (email) to them and apparently their Sandbox doesn't work

Comment: so we should assume that it will work in the live version.

Comment: That's where they told me to test - and I can't because I don't have Kenyian phone number so I'm looking for alternative if you find one